# Search form redirect to home page after you search with Cyrillic letters only

Tags: php, wordpress

I have strange behavior in search functionality in WordPress.
I have a problem with search in [this](https://fakenews.rs/) website.
When i search with Latin letters (Stefan Kosanović), it's perfect, but when i search with Cyrillic letters (Стефан Косановић), it keeps redirect me on homepage.
Locally, everything is working fine, and local version is 1:1 with live version, so in files there is no difference.
Also PHP and WP versions are the same.

Far as i saw, if you search with Cyrillic letters, URL is not passing URL decode.So for example, space is not replaced with `+` symbol, etc.

Is it possible that hosting settings restrict some functionality?

Answer (score 0):

If you copy and paste the url to IDE you will see something like

```
https://fakenews.rs/?s=%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BD%20%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%9B"
```

paste that to urldecode

```
echo urldecode ( "https://fakenews.rs/?s=%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BD%20%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%9B" );
```

and you will see: `https://fakenews.rs/?s=Стефан Косановић`
and that is the expected output from the url..
To solve the problem, what you can try is to decode the url and paste it as a string to the search query or try and convert letters to latin and paste to the query

Comment: Already do that, or maybe i do it all wrong?
https://gist.github.com/Soullighter/ccd14c602def2c64e6a8ea1ca31326ba

Comment: I need to translate it anyway, because content on website is on Latin only, and language conversion is done by JS.

Comment: If you search for Stefan Kosanović, the url outputs https://fakenews.rs/?s=Stefan+Kosanovi%C4%87 loock at "ć" it is not ć it is UTF-8 encoding https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=256&unicodeinhtml=hex

Comment: UTF-8  encode all ŽĆČDŽŠ! NOTE these are latin chars you need to encode..

Comment: I will try that. In meantime i used some other server to test if search will work there, and it's working. So it's probably server config or something. Need to speak with support to figure it out.

Comment: you can also echo get_locale(); and check if there is a difference on dev / prod if there is a difference use   setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8"); to set the same encoding. I samo lagano ime!  :)